# Kafka Cluster ID for HiveMQ Extension

Tags: apache-kafka, hivemq

I setup a 3 node Kafka and Zookeeper cluster on 1 machine. Now I need the cluster ID for my HiveMQ Extension.

When the Kafka gets started, the logs provide the cluster id of a long string.

I used that id, but its really not working.

Answer (score 1):

No, in meta.properties I need to set the cluster.id and than pass it to hivemq extension.

It's working now!!!